# Convert BSON Document string property to Datetime object

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query, bson

I stored data on Mongo db as below  document

```
public class BookingDocument{

     public string Id   {get;set;}
    
     public List<ActivityDocument> Activities  {get;set;}

     public string Status {get;set;}

}


public class ActivityDocument {

  public string DateFrom {get;set;}

  public string Status {get;set;}

}
```

I have to filter BookingList Collection with the requested date pass from user

```
    public async Task<List<BookingDocument>> ActivityBookingList(string start,string end) 
    {

    DateTime startDate;

    DateTime endDate;


           startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(end + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

**solution 1**

    var filter = new BsonDocument("$expr", new BsonDocument(
                            "$and", new BsonArray{
    
                        new BsonDocument("$gte",new BsonArray{
                                new BsonDocument("$dateFromString","$Activities.DateFrom"), startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        }),

                    new BsonDocument("$lte",new BsonArray{
                            new BsonDocument("$dateFromString","$Activities.DateFrom"), endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        })


                        }
                    ));

totalCount = await BookingCollection
                 .Find(Builders<BookingDocument>.Filter.And(filter))
                 .CountDocumentsAsync();
}
```

returns

> $dateFromString only supports an object as an argument, found: string

error

I tried below options as well

**Solution 2**

```
 var filter = new BsonDocument("$expr", new BsonDocument(
                            "$and", new BsonArray{

 new BsonDocument("$gte",new BsonArray{
                            new BsonDocument("$toDate","$Activities.DateFrom"),startDate
                        }),
                        new BsonDocument("$lte",new BsonArray{
                            new BsonDocument("$toDate","$Activities.DateFrom"),endDate
                        })
                        }
                    ));

   

 totalCount = await BookingCollection
                     .Find(Builders<BookingDocument>.Filter.And(filter))
                     .CountDocumentsAsync();
    
    }
```

return

> Unsupported conversion from array to date in $convert with no onError
> value

error

but below is return the output but it only checks first  element in the activity list

```
var filter = new BsonDocument("$expr", new BsonDocument(
                        "$and", new BsonArray{

           new BsonDocument("$gte",new BsonArray{
                        new BsonDocument("$dateFromString",new BsonDocument("dateString", new BsonDocument("$arrayElemAt", new BsonArray { "$Activities.DateFrom", 0 }))),startDate
                    }),

          new BsonDocument("$lte",new BsonArray{
                        new BsonDocument("$dateFromString",new BsonDocument("dateString", new BsonDocument("$arrayElemAt", new BsonArray { "$Activities.DateFrom", 0 }))),endDate
                    })

                        }
                    ));


 totalCount = await BookingCollection
                     .Find(Builders<BookingDocument>.Filter.And(filter))
                     .CountDocumentsAsync();
```

please help to sort out this issue

Comment: Would be great if you can share a sample document in the MongoDB collection. How did you store the date in the document, as string or DateTime type?

Comment: @YongShun as string

Comment: You should **never** store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects.